# How to interpret 3rd hand not covering?

Tags: bridge

Consider West on lead in the middle of the game.

```
Dummy   
QJ976    

Declarer    
A103
```

West leads 8 from the suit. Declarer plays 6 from dummy. East plays 5. Declarer wins with 10.

Couple of questions about this

1. What do we interpret here from opposition's play - is the K with West? Or is it with East & East didn't cover for some reason? If yes, then what reason?
2. Was playing 6 from the dummy the right play? Or would it have been better to play the Q hoping for East to cover with K if he did have it?

Comment: Please give the contract, the whole hand, the play so far (if it's not the first trick) and East/West's lead and signalling agreements.  All of that could be relevant.  Bridge is complicated.

Comment: The bidding is also relevant (because it tells us what the defenders know about declarer's hand).

Comment: At a minimum, we need to know if the declaring side is short of entries to dummy and or short of entries to hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly without knowing the rest of the hand.  Does East have reason to guess that South has the ace?  What does West's lead of the 8 mean?  Where in the hand are we?  What is the contract?  NT or trump suit, and is this trump or not?

Either way, W probably isn't underleading A8x.  Even if there were no other suit to play, there's just no reason not to play A. So E knows A is in South most likely; there's no reason for E to play the K there.  But, E also might have only two - 5 is a weird choice otherwise.  Why play 5 from K52 or K54?  It's not like E wants to encourage...

On the other hand, W really shouldn't underlead Kxx or Kxxx.  No matter the contract, it's probably a bad lead.  It's possible W has no choice - if this is the only suit left, for example - but if this is early and W likely has a choice, it makes more sense for E to have the K based on this lead.  It's just unclear why W led the suit in the first place.

You also may want to see their carding agreement - 8 from 842 is a reasonable lead in some agreements, it's not in others.  Would they lead 8 from 82?  2 from 842?  It's possible you can eliminate some holdings from the lead of the 8, but again this depends on their card.

As far as the play of the 6 goes, Declarer is announcing that they have the T by not covering, so they should cover with the 9.  There's just no reason not to, not even transportation-related reasons.  Put the 9 on and see if that draws out the K.  It might, might not, who knows, but you can always cover with the T anyway if you prefer to be in hand.

Comment: Those underfed aces can be oh-so dangerous.